# Send Email through GMail behind proxy in Java

Tags: java, email, proxy, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send email through Gmail server in JAVA.
 Here is my actual **code** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException  {

    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
    final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    // Get a Properties object
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
    props.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "xxx.xx.xxx.xx");
    props.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");

    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");


    final String username = "username";
    final String password = "password";
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    System.out.println(props.getProperty("http.proxyHost"));
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });

    // -- Create a new message --
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    // -- Set the FROM and TO fields --
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("username@gmail.com"));
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("to@gmail.com", false));
    msg.setSubject("Hello");
    msg.setText("How are you");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    Transport.send(msg);
    System.out.println("Message sent.");
}
```

This code works perfectly fine on connections without proxy. When I run the same code on my office network which connects through proxy it doesn't work. Please help me to find a solution.

The output which I get when I run the code in office network,

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.2
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
null
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL false
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 465; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2053)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at proxytest.GmailSender.main(GmailSender.java:61)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
```

Comment: [How do I configure JavaMail to work through my proxy server?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#proxy)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks for the reply. Is there any other way to send e-mail behind proxy other than using javamail ?

Comment: I can also try other programming languages too for this to work. Please suggest me if there is any possible way. @Seelenvirtuose

Comment: I am not very familiar with JavaMail. I just found this while searching. Maybe the FAQ helps you.

Comment: If anybody has answers regarding the questions in my previous comments. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to SSL enable to use a proxy through gmail server.

```
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "true");
```